# Printing linked lists in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently in the process of learning C and am now studying linked lists. I think I wrapped my head around the most basic concepts. Now I would like to print such a list. I implemented my own method to print the contents of the list but they were semi-efficient. I found learn-c.org and liked their method of doing it a lot but I seem unable to make use of it.

Their method is the following:

```
void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I created a node named "head"

```
node_t * head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

and tried calling the method with "head" as an argument which is - apparently - wrong. Means: `print_list(head)` shows me an "conflicting types" error.

Anyone got any input on that? I tried around already and from my understanding the method expects a pointer to a node_t structure.

Edit: Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

int main(){
node_t * head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
if (head == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

head->val = 1;
head->next = NULL;

print_list(head);

}

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code instead of discribing it.

Comment: This should work, please post a [MCVE].

Comment: You do remember to declare a prototype of the `print_list` before you call it? Besides the MCVE, can you please include the *complete* error output, in full and unedited, and with any information notes.

Comment: Sorry guys, added everything.

Comment: Move `print_list` above `main` or add a prototype. Pay attention to compiler warnings, or even better, use a flag to turn warnings into errors. This will help you a lot.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought about that first but brushed it off... for whatever reason. Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: Also, not to rain on the source of that code, but it really should be taking a `const node_t *` since printing a list isn't going to be changing it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @unwind, I will try to keep things like that in mind. Already changed my code fitting to your recommendation.

Comment: There are no "methods" in C. There are "functions". There's a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `print_list` the compiler doesn't know what it is. You must declare everything you use, before you use it.

So something like

```
// Declare the function prototype, so compiler knows about it
void print_list(node_t * head);

int main(void)
{
    node_t * head;

    // Create and populate list...

    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}

// Define the function implementation
void print_list(node_t * head)
{
    // The implementation of the function...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare a prototype:

```
...
typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head);  // <<< add this

int main() {
...
```

In C you can use functions even without them being declared, the compiler then implicitly assumes that the function has any number of arguments and that it returns an int. This is a leftover from very old C standards. Modern compilers usually issue warnings if you do this.

What happens in your case:

- the compilers stumbles upon `print_list(head);` assuming that it return `int`
- then it stumbles upon `void print_list(node_t * head) {` where suddenly the return type is nomore `int` but `void` and hence the compilation error.